# Cannot save GeoDjango Point in model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, geodjango

I'm building a website with Django and, in some page, the user can use a geolocation system to save its current location. At the beginning, the page display a google map centered on a random location. Then the user clicks on a button, it locates him and its current location is displayed on the map. The field `latitude` and `longitude` of a form are automatically filled. After that, the user can submit the form and a view is responsible for saving a Point object in the database with the latitude and the longitude. The problem is that the Point is not created : when I go to the admin interface, we see that the location attribute is not initialized and when I try to get the `latitude` and `longitude` from the Point in another view, I get the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'y'` that proves that the Point is never created. I don't understand why because the view correctly get the latitude and longitude values (I display them in a message to be sure they are correct).

Here is the relevant parts of my code :
models.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as models2

class UserAdvanced(models2.Model):
    localisation = models2.PointField(blank = True, null = True)
```

forms.py

```
class LocationForm(forms.Form):
    latitude = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    longitude = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

def inscription_fin(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LocationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            longitude = float(form.cleaned_data['longitude']) #float(request.POST.get('longitude')) : I've tried this also but it doesn't work either.
            latitude = float(form.cleaned_data['latitude']) #float(request.POST.get('latitude'))
            request.user.useradvanced.localisation = Point(longitude, latitude)
            messages.success(request, "Latitude : " + str(latitude) + " / Longitude : " + str(longitude))
            return redirect("home")
    else:
        form = LocationForm()

    return render(request, 'inscription/inscription_fin.html', {'form': form})
```

html

```
<button id="find-me" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary btn-login text-uppercase font-weight-bold mb-2">Localisez-moi maintenant</button><br/>
<div id="map" style="height: 100%"></div>
<p id = "status"></p>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="fieldWrapper form-group"> Latitude : <input type="text" name="latitude" value="" id="latitude" required="required"/></div>
  <div class="fieldWrapper form-group"> Longitude : <input type="text" name="longitude" value="" id="longitude" required="required"/></div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary btn-block btn-login text-uppercase font-weight-bold mb-2" value="Soumettre ma localisation" />
</form>
```

javascript

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    lln = {lat: 50.66981991272638, lng: 4.615554319641566}
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {center: lln, zoom: 15});
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: lln, map: map});
  }

  function geoFindMe() {
    const status = document.querySelector('#status');
    var map;

    function success(position) {
      const latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
      const longitude = position.coords.longitude;

      status.textContent = '';
      document.getElementById('longitude').value = longitude;
      document.getElementById('latitude').value = latitude;
      loc = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {center: loc, zoom: 17});
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: loc, map: map});
   }

   function error() {
     status.textContent = 'Nous ne parvenons pas à obtenir votre localisation. Veuillez réessayer plus tard.';
   }

   if (!navigator.geolocation) {
     status.textContent = 'La géolocalisation n\'est pas supportée par votre navigateur';
   }
   else {
     status.textContent = 'Localisation…';
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
   }
 }

 document.querySelector('#find-me').addEventListener('click', geoFindMe);
</script>
```

I know the error is probably dummy but I've searched a lot and I can't find the solution by myself. I thank you in advance for your reponse !

Comment: Is `Point` a model? If so you need to save it. Or you can do `Point.objects.create(x=x_val, y=y_val)`

Comment: No it's not a model, it's the point object from GeoDjango, imported using ```from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point``` in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save `request.user.useradvanced` after you do `request.user.useradvanced.localisation = Point(longitude, latitude)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one in your function views.py.

if form.is_valid():

```
        post = form.save(commit=False)

        log = float(form.cleaned_data['longitude'])
        lat = float(form.cleaned_data['latitude'])

        # if you are using this srid = 4326
        pnt = Point(log,lat,srid = 4326)
        wkb_w = WKBWriter()
        geom_write = wkb_w.write_hex(pnt)

        post.geom = pnt
        post.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem has already been solved, I forgot to use the save() function to save the changes in the database